# List[(Int,Int)] Into List[Int] - Seeking Advice

Tags: scala

Ok, so iv'e done about an hour of searching can't find any realistic ways to take a list of tuple ints I.E
`val e = List((5,10),(10,13),(30,37))`
And without using a mutable list i want to create a new list based off the old one.... however in this new list instead of tuples i want all the integers in between the 2 values.
I.E the Above LIST into => `List(6,7,8,9,11,12,31,32,33,34,35,36)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TL:DR List of Tuples[Int,Int] into new List of values inbetween the two into ints untupled.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> val e = List((5,10),(10,13),(30,37))
e: List[(Int, Int)] = List((5,10), (10,13), (30,37))

scala> e.flatMap(t => t._1+1 until t._2)
res1: List[Int] = List(6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)
```

Comment: last thing, what if i wanted to return all the numbers inbetween + the number itself I.E (5,10) would be 5,6,7,8,9,10 not just 6,7,8,9

Comment: `e.flatMap(t => t._1 to t._2)`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `Range` using `until` for each pair in the input sequence and use `flatMap` to combine them:

```
e.flatMap { case (le, ue) => (le + 1).until(ue) }
```